# What is the underlying meaning of 'an'?

Tags: verb, prefix

According to [the following site](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~german/Grammatik/Wortbildung/Separables.html)

The prefix "an-" usually carries the meanings "at," "begin," "on," "onward," "to," or "toward". Some of the many possibilities:

Yes, I concede but the following verbs makes no sense to me:

**anlegen and angeben**:

**angeben**, according to the dictionary (dict.cc), means:

*to represent, declare, quote,*

and

**anlegen** means:

*to invest, create (in terms of the Internet), put in (makes sense), compile, apply*

although for me anlegen may take the meaning of 'an', angeben seems so detached from the meanings of an. Can anyone explain how the addition of 'an' lead to the above meaning of angeben and anlegen? or do I have to memorise them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prefixes don't carry general meanings. In most cases, they have common ethymological roots with the same meaning, but these have often diverged in meaning over the centuries.

Additionally, each of the two verbs you give has very different meanings. If you wanted to understand the `an-` for each of these meanings, you'd need to be very flexible. I'd say this is very difficult for native speakers as well.

But it's possible for at leat one meaning each.

**anlegen** = *to create (not only in the sense of the Internet)*: here the `an-` carries the meaning of *begin*. The act of `anlegen` ist the begin of the following process.

- `ein Beet/Feld anlegen`: you create the bed/field is the begin of the agricultural process
- `Geld anlegen`: you create an account at the beginning of earning money that way
- `eine Webseite anlegen`: you create the website at the beginning. Afterwards others can use it.

**angeben** = *to declare or indicate*: here the `an-` carries the meaning of `to`. The act of `geben` is directed at (to) somebody particular.

- `beim Zoll Waren angeben`: you declare your duties to the customs officers.
- `jemanden angeben=jemanden ankündigen`: "darauf leszt sich Daniel beim könig angeben." (Mathesius 80ᵃ) Daniel is declared to the King.

Answer (score 2):

"an" bezeichnet eine unmittelbare Nähe zweier Objekte auf gleicher Ebene (im Vergleich zu *bei*, *vor*, *in*, *auf* oder *unter*). Das [Grimmsche Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GA03324) beschreibt es auch anhand seines Verhältnisses zu anderen Präpositionen:

> *an* bezeichnet die oberfläche, *ab* das ihr abgewandte, *in* das inwendige, *aus* (eigentlich ur = goth. us) das auswendige, wer *an*
>   den berg geht, geht nicht *in* den berg, wer *ab* dem berge kommt, kam
>   nicht *aus* ihm. *an* ist stärker als *bei*, schwächer als *zu*, hält
>   zwischen ihnen gleichsam die mitte. der *bei* das(!) haus*) gehende
>   ist noch nicht *an* ihm, der *an* dem haus stehende noch nicht *zu*
>   hause; einer der den ring *bei* sich trägt, trägt ihn darum nicht *an*
>   sich und der das brot *bei* sich nimmt*) kann es hernach *zu* sich
>   nehmen.

Diese Grundbedeutung verbindet sich als Präfix zu Verben, die ebenfalls eine Handlung oder Bewegung mit räumlichem Bezug beschreiben oder für eine davon abgeleitete abstraktere Vorstellung stehen. Oft hat auch dasselbe zusammengesetzte Verb eine konkrete und eine abgeleitete Bedeutung. *Anlegen* ist dafür ein gutes Beispiel:

Konkret:

```
Anlegen eines Dominosteins an die anderen oder von Karten auf dem Tisch (v.t.)
Anlegen eines Bootes am Steg oder Schiffes am Pier (v.i.)
Anlegen eines Kleidungsstücks oder Schmuckstücks (anziehen) (v.t.)
Jemandem Handschellen anlegen (v.t.)
```

Abstrakter:

```
An etwas Hand anlegen (ein Werkstück zur Bearbeitung übernehmen)
```

Abstrakt:

```
Anlegen eines Lagers, Hauses, einer Siedlung: wie Dominosteine ein Teil an das andere legen (begründen = planen -> errichten)
Ein Dossier, eine Akte anlegen, aktuell auch: ein Dokument, einen Ordner auf dem Computer anlegen (beginnen / begründen, um es weiterzuführen)
Es darauf anlegen, eine bestimmte Wirkung oder ein Ergebnis zu erzielen (planen -> verwirklichen)
Geld anlegen (nutzbringend an-, einsetzen, verwenden bzw. vermehren), früher z.B. auch: sein Leben gut anlegen
```

Dieses Prinzip gilt auch für "angeben", doch mit dem Unterschied, dass diesem Verb sowohl die konkrete Bedeutung ("geben") als auch die Vielseitigkeit von "anlegen" fehlt. Es hat nur auf verbale Kommunikation übertragene Bedeutungen:

```
etwas nennen (v.t.)
etwas anführen, aufzählen (v.t.)
etwas berichten (v.t.)
jemanden angeben (v.t.), altertümlich für "verraten" 
übertreiben, prahlen, aufschneiden (v.i.)
```

*) "bei" ist heute eine Ortspräposition mit Dativ, keine Bewegungspräposition mit Akkusativ mehr. Die Verbalkomposita mit "bei" enthalten aber noch diesen ursprünglichen Gebrauch des Wortes.

Answer (score 1):

Im allgemeinen haben Verbalpräfixe wie an-/be-/-er etc mehrere, manchmal viele Bedeutungen. Verbalpräfixe werden in Lexika noch nicht generell erfasst und wenn, dann ist ihre Analyse nie erschöpfend.

"anlegen" - Man könnte erklären, ein Boot legt am Ufer/Bootssteg an.

"angeben" - Der Lehrer hat den Tag der Prüfung angegeben: Er hat den Tag an die Schüler gegeben, im Sinn von: ihnen bekannt gegeben.

Answer (score -2):

Prefixes do carry meanings, which the average German just does not know.

*-an* means a movement towards something and stopping right before, slightly touching.

It applies to your words:

**anlegen**:

- a ship touches *anlegs* at the quai
- in case of money, you put it somewhere (lay it there)

**angeben**:

- you give the ... whatever information .. there

Don't believe people who claim that in German things without general meaning exist.